# NextJS won't render images in production

Tags: docker, next.js, production-environment, production

I have a nextjs app that is using images from the public folder and outside sources. It works in development and not in production. It even works locally using the same production environment with docker and not when deployed. I am fetching some country flag icons from `countryflagsapi.com`. Public folder images also do not work.

Request URL: `domain.com/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcountryflagsapi.com%2Fpng%2FUA&w=16&q=75`

Request response: `"url" parameter is not allowed`

This is the browser console error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of contentFilterPrivate.isURLBlocked(string url, contentFilterPrivate.ElementType type, string sitekey): No matching signature.
    at FilterContent.isUrlFiltered_ (filter_content.js:202:44)
    at FilterContent.onResourceError_ (filter_content.js:229:14)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (filter_content.js:177:28)
```

next.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withImages = require('next-images');

const plugins = [[withLess, withImages]];

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, {
    images: {
        domains: [
            'countryflagsapi.com',
        ],
    },
});
```

I copy everything the app requires in the Dockerfile.

```
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docker file provided by the next `with-docker` example, the only difference I find is the copy line points to the *root* vs specifying `next.config.js` again.

```
# You only need to copy next.config.js 
# if you are NOT using the default configuration
 COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
```

vs

`COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js`

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile#L45

Additionally, can you check if the file exists in that location post deployment?

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
```

this command worked with nextjs 12 version for getting photos